# Xcode quits my application say 'Finished running App' when testing on ipad

Tags: xcode, ipad

my app built in cocos2d. it works fine on simulator (ipad,iphone,iphone5) and also debug fine in my devices ipod 5th and 4rth generation but not working fine on ipad device(ios 5.1). i did recieve warrnings two times in my rootview controller. when i hit play button on ipad ipad just quits my without anything in xcode 'log'.
it just display 'Finished running APP'.
any suggetion about how or which is the best way to figuring out the bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Instruments and figure out how much memory you are using. Look at how much RAM you're using but also **video memory** with the *Open GL ES Driver Profiler*.
Check those numbers against the device specs. You will need to do different things depending on which type of memory you are running out.
Cocos2d manages a lot of objects especially Graphic objects and releases them automatically. If you are running low on RAM you should look at what big unmanaged objects you are using but also tiny ones that you allocate extremely often.
For Video Memory, do not use big 'empty' images (like background frames for menus), you can use a Scale9Sprite (http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/18/topics/8335) which will tile the center of that image.

Comment: i have used instruments but only shows low memory warning with black bar on top then terminates

Answer (score 0):

This happens when your app runs out of memory; you need to reduce its memory usage and try again.

Comment: i am new cocos2d and i am not sure the best way to release objects that cocos2d is using e:g; spritesheet, sounds.